# How do you get a new house for Michael and Trevor

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How to get a new house for Michael and Trevor? I've tried the online apartment but can't buy that, duh, but I tried it anyway!

Answer (score 5):

For Michael, Trevor or Franklin, it is simply not possible to buy a new house for them. You can only buy apartments online.

Answer (score 1):

In single player you cannot buy different houses you must simply stay with the default houses the entire single player. However in online multiplayer you may buy apartments using the internet app on your phone then choose the real estate app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to buy a new home for each other character.
Just a mission of Franklin's can get a home for Franklin.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way possible you can buy a house with Michael, Trevor, or Franklin.

Answer (score -2):

You can buy a shack in Rockford hills under Devin weston's house

Answer (score -3):

You can buy one with all the characters but you install the patch 5.5.1

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you think you could edit your answer to be a bit clearer? Do you need to install patch version 5.5.1 before you can buy houses with Michael and Trevor?